# is there any way to load data from excel in to text boxes of html web page and submit it dynamically?

Tags: java, javascript, html, excel

instead of entering several values in respective text box and submitting it... is there any way to automate the process such that it will automatically pick values from EXCEL sheet and enters in to respective text fields and clicks on submit

Can we do this in java if yes kindly help me out with the best way.. suggest me if there is any other alternative solution..

Comment: POSSIBLE but not something I would suggest unless yo're ready to parse Excel files client-side with JavaScript and file API (!!!) or you want to **upload Excel file to server for parsing**.

Comment: if you can find the xmlhttp post data when you submit webpage,then you can read excel sheet from java and post to webpage .

Comment: Honestly! Dont help people who ask this kind of question or your email inbox will show a lot more spam in the future..

Comment: Dabrion there are several Workspace Webmail's features for spam management to prevent unsolicited junk email from clogging up your Inbox on top of that if we use this functionality for other things like signup still we can overcome the risk by captcha or some other means.. however, i asked the question to automate the process which will save my time.. currently entering the data and submitting it manually is killing lot of time..

Comment: Adriano Repetti and getlost thanks for your reply guys. here the problem is the web page where i am entering the data and submitting is not our website so, i don't have any access to it like database or server side coding... only option is client side..

Comment: OK, that's pretty different. Then AUTOMATE this process. Using a web client component (depends language you're using), you can read excel data and fill forms automatically. Basically same tools you use for automated web UI testing but with little bit more code to read data from Excel.

Comment: You should not have to use a web-interface for this kind of task. Do you have access to the backend. Should be easier to migrate the spreadsheet data into a database directly.

Comment: Adriano Repetti and Dabrion thanks for your reply. i finished the task. Adriano YOU ARE RIGHT.. with the help of SELENIUM i have automated the process.. thanks a lot.. Dabrion as i mentioned earlier that i don't have any direct access to the back end so i have done it as suggested by Adriano.. now its working perfectly..